# UnsafeMutablePointer Warning with Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, pointers, mutable

I had this:

```
let alphaPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>(mutating: alpha) as UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>?
```

Which now I get the warning:

> Initialization of 'UnsafeMutablePointer' (aka
>   'UnsafeMutablePointer') results in a dangling pointer

Detailed warning consists of:

> 1. Implicit argument conversion from '[vImagePixelCount]' (aka 'Array') to 'UnsafePointer' (aka
>      'UnsafePointer') produces a pointer valid only for the duration
>      of the call to 'init(mutating:)'
> 2. Use the 'withUnsafeBufferPointer' method on Array in order to explicitly convert argument to buffer pointer valid for a defined
>      scope

Is there a way around this?

Comment: You just need to follow the instructions shown in the Detailed warning.

Comment: This was always wrong, now you’re busted. Be happy!

Answer (score 10):

Try this

```
var bytes = [UInt8]()
let uint8Pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: bytes.count)
uint8Pointer.initialize(from: &bytes, count: bytes.count)
```

Comment: Where is `alpha`, the variable mentioned in the question's code?

Comment: Legit this worked for me!  Thank you.  btw Scotty, uint8Pointer == alphaPtr.

Comment: awesome! I was struggling with crash due to UnsafeMutablePointer ! your answer helped me thank you @rajasekhar-pasupuleti 

I had an array pixelBuffer - [Float32] so I did this 
 
        let floatPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float32>.allocate(capacity:pixelBuffer.count)
        floatPointer.initialize(from: &pixelBuffer, count: pixelBuffer.count)

Answer (score 7):

It was never safe to do this, and the compiler now is warning you more aggressively.

```
let alphaPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer ...
```

At the end of this line, `alphaPtr` is already invalid. There is no promise that what it points to is still allocated memory.

Instead, you need to nest whatever usage you need into a `withUnsafeMutablePointer()` (or `withUnsafePointer()`) block. If you cannot nest it into a block (for example, if you were storing the pointer or returning it), there is no way to make that correct. You'll have to redesign your data management to not require that.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need use the `withUnsafeBufferPointer` method from Array as

```swift
var alphaPtr: UnsafeBufferPointer = alpha.withUnsafeBufferPointer { $0 }
```

that's command produce a pointer optional if you need working with a specific type could you you use `bindMemory(to:)` or other function that match with you requirements.

Sometimes use a `&alpha` if you need a `UnsafeRawPointer` as a function parameter.

Comment: This is not any more correct than the original code. There is no promise that `alphaPtr` is valid after the closing brace. If you use `alphaPtr` in any way it's undefined behavior, which is what the warning is telling you.

Comment: that gets me: Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>' to closure result type 'UnsafePointer<UInt8>?'